# What is the meaning of static?

Tags: c, static

Consider following code:

```
static uint8_t tab[] = {1, 2};

void foo() {
    uint8_t tab2[] = {1, 2};
}
```

I have here two arrays one is with `static` keyword the second is within function. How should I properly name each of them? Because those two are static. I know the difference that `tab` array will exist forever unlike `tab2` which exists only when executing function `foo()`. If `tab2` is static array which dies after function exit shouldn't it be called another? What are proper names of those arrays accroding to programming theroy?

Another example:

```
void bar() {
  static uint8_t tab[] = { 1, 2 };
}
```

What is proper name according to programming-theory of such variable? "static of static" array?

Comment: `Because those two are static`...how so?

Comment: `If tab2 is static array which dies after function exit`...well, it is not having static storage.

Comment: Edited the title; this is *very much C*, not "programming theory".

Comment: `static` variables in the global scope means something very different from `static` variables in a local scope. You might want to read e.g. [this storage-class reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration).

Comment: "_If tab2 is static array ..._" - it isn't. You can tell, because it isn't declared with the `static` keyword. "_... which dies after function exit ..._" - it does go out of scope, precisely because it is _not_ static.

Comment: And variable naming is a very subjective matter, which makes it not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wonder if OP is trying to ask "what would we call this type"?

Comment: I mean, there is confusion calling array `tab2` "static". Because it mixes with `static` keyword

Comment: You can say that "`tab` is a static variable and `tab2` is an automatic variable". Or that "`tab` has static storage duration and `tab2` has automatic storage duration".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `static` keyword means [static storage duration and internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) (unless at block scope, where it means static storage duration and *no* linkage as block-scoped things are never linked).

Your `tab2` *is not static*, it has *automatic* storage duration and no linkage. (There is even a keyword for that, `auto`, which is implied and not normally used however. Don't confuse this with C++, which has "recycled" that keyword for a completely different meaning.)

What *identifier* you give your variables -- e.g. `tab` or `tab2` -- is up to you. But what they *are* is very well defined by the language:

- Your first `tab` is a *static global* array of two `uint8_t`. It has *static* storage duration and *internal* linkage.
- Your `tab2` is a *block scope* array of two `uint8_t`. It has *automatic* storage duration and *no* linkage.
- Your second `tab` is a *static block scope* array of two `uint8_t`. It has *static* storage duration and *no* linkage.

Comment: Makes sense for me, I will follow these terms.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here. That's not entirely your fault, seeing as "static" means at least two different things in C.

Your `tab2` is not static. It does not have static storage duration, nor is it in any way related to static storage. It's just an array. It's a local variable that is an array.

Your `tab` is a global array which gives it static storage duration, and has internal linkage due to the keyword `static`. If it were within a function, it would be "function-static".

If I were you, I wouldn't worry too much about terminology; instead, worry about making your program do what you want it to do!

Comment: Not to mention the internal linkage for the global array.

Comment: `tab` is not a global array, precisely because it is declared with the keyword static.

Comment: @WilliamPursell "Global" relates to scope, not linkage. It is at namespace scope, so global.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Oops how did I get here 

Answer (score 2):

Clearing out terms:

```
1) static uint8_t tab[] = {1, 2};

2) void foo() { uint8_t tab2[] = {1, 2}; ...
```

**Scope:**
1) Is a variable declared at *file scope*. 2) is a variable declared at *local scope*. Scope determines where a variable is accessible.

- Local variables are obviously only accessible inside the scope where they were declared.
- File scope variables are accessible throughout the whole *translation unit* where the variable is declared. A translation unit is the .c file and all .h files it includes.

**Storage duration:**

- *Static storage duration* means that a variable will persist throughout the execution of the program. Such variables are always initialized before `main()` is called, either to zero or to a specific value.
- *Automatic storage duration* means that a variable will no longer be valid when the program counter leaves the scope where that variable was declared. They have inderminate values unless initialized explicitly by the programmer.

All variables declared at file scope has static storage duration.
All variables declared as `static` has static storage duration.
All variables declared at local scope, without `static`, has automatic storage duration.

(Some other cases exist for `extern` etc but that's not relevant here. There is the term linkage, which I won't address here.)

Knowing this, then "because those two are static" doesn't make sense. They have a statically set and fixed size, but that's all they have in common.

---

Regarding naming, that's subjective and up to your own coding standard. Give them intuitive names explaining what they contain, rather than what type they are.

Some older coding standards liked to regard `static`-declared file scope variables as private variables and therefore used a `_` prefix to indicate this. But this is bad practice, because it collides with naming rules of the C standard (and the POSIX standard).

Answer (score 1):

> What are proper names of those arrays accroding to programming theory?

Naming identifiers is not a part of programming theory. How you should name them is a matter of best practice, conventions, company standards and such. And how this should be done is very opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

C has a full bunch of *classes* (name is mine) of variables, with variations of scope (for what part of code the variable can be accessed) and duration.

At file level (outside of any function):

- no qualifier: duration: full length of the program, scope: file, accessible as extern: from any compilation unit of the program (said to have external linkage)
- static: duration: full length of the program, scope: file, accessible as extern: no (said to have internal linkage)

Inside a function or a bloc:

- no qualifier: duration: the bloc (the variable vanishes at the end of the bloc where it is declared), scope: the bloc, accessible as extern: no (said to be automatic, and has no linkage)
- static: duration: full length of the program, scope: the bloc, accessible as extern: no (said to be bloc static, and has no linkage)

In addition, a variable can be declared as `extern`. In that case, the variable is only declared, and has to be defined elsewhere **with the same declaration** in the same compilation unit or in another one.

To be exhaustive, C has another category for duration: allocated. It is used for objects that are created through malloc and that persist until they are explicitely freed. But beware: the programmer is responsable to keep a pointer to the object with the normal scope rules to be able to free it.

Answer (score 1):

`static` on filescope declarations means "local to this translation unit".

Example:

```
static int variable=42; 
static int function(){return 0;}
//won't be visible in other translation units
```

`static` on block-scoped declarations means "with static storage duration":

Example:

```
uint8_t *bar() {
  static uint8_t tab[] = { 1, 2 };
  return  &tab[0]; 
  //ok with static but pretty much always an error otherwise
}
int how_many_times_i_ran(){ static unsigned x; return x++; }
```

`static` inside the brackets of "array-typed" function parameters means the integer expression that follows denotes the minimum number of elements that the pointer must point to.

```
void take3(int Three[static 2+1]); 

void call()
{
    take3((int[3]){0}); //OK
    take3(0); //undefined
    take3((int[2]){0}); //undefined
}
```

Comment: `int Three[static 2+1]`, does it compile? I have never seen it before.

Comment: @shjeff Turns out [this is C99](https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html). I didn't know that either.